# JQuery: "$ is not a function" with multiple JavaScript Files in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, razor, typeerror

I have a javaScript file providing dynamic tabs with jQuery that works just fine on its own:

**SpecificationAndAvailabilityTabs.js**

```
var height;

//Have the specifications tab open by default.
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tabs #defaultOpen').addClass('active');
    $('.tabs #Overview').show();
    height = $('.tabs #Overview').height();
});

function openTab(evt, tabName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active",     "");
    }

    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
    $('.tabs #' + tabName).height(height);//Give the Availability content      area the same height as given to the Specification content area.
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Now I am trying to introduce a second file in the same directory, right now I am just trying to execute some very basic manipulation to see if it works but it does not:

**AvailabilityIcons.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("p").hide();
    });
});
```

And here are the scripts being added to the View in my ASP.NET application:

```
...
//Script for tab toggle functionality
Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Themes/WCA/Scripts/SpecificationAndAvailabilityTabs.js");
//Script for Dynamic Availability Icons
Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Themes/WCA/Scripts/AvailabilityIcons.js");
...
```

Now the problem does not even occur with the second file itself, but for some reason it causes all references to '$' in all javaScript files to go unrecognized:
[image]

From my research I keep running into the common solutions of avoiding conflicts with both

```
(function($) {
    /*My Code*/
}(jQuery);
```

as well as using:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

But no combination of these two solutions on both of the files above has managed to resolve anything for me. I will note again that the first file works 100% if I take away the second "AppendScriptParts". Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you including jQuery itself somewhere?

Comment: ^ and if you are, make sure jquery.js comes before any other files which rely on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually a very silly issue that I had before... I keep forgetting that Google Chrome saves JavaScript files to cache like it does with CSS files, so it was not updating its copy of my files every time I was updating them... They must be reset with Ctrl + F5. Sorry to waste anybodys time, but thank you for the efforts!

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add that if you included jQuery, make sure it is included before your script.

This is because your script is dependent on it, therefore it will not run if you include jQuery after your script.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Jquery with multiple other scripts I would recommend not using $ and switch that out for jQuery in the event that the other scripts are using $ in some form. For Example:

```
$(function() {

});
```

Becomes

```
jQuery(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure jQuery library is included.

Comment: So it turns out I actually did not have it included, but how was the first file working before if this is required? Also now that I am including it, I am still getting one report of that same error as well as a new one saying "autocomplete" is not a function.

Comment: Correction, It was actually included in the razor layout my view is using.

Comment: maybe the 1st one was not related with jQuery. it maybe written in javascript.